# Why datatable ignores initial spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Datatable does not take initial spaces, so when i insert it into database and retrieve it by select statement and display it on page using stringBuilder, Initial spaces are gone and text does not appear on screen as it is written in textbox

```
DataTable1.Rows[0][0]=TextBox1.Text;
```

This is how I insert into database

```
 public static void Insert(DataTable table)
        {
            StringBuilder Col = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder Val = new StringBuilder();
            string Query, finalVal;
            int i, j;
            int count = 0;
            int ColumnCount = table.Columns.Count;
            for (i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                if (table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(r => !r.IsNull(table.Columns[i].ColumnName)))
                {
                    Col.Append(table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                    Col.Append(",");
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Col.Remove(Col.Length - 1, 1);
            string[] columnName = Col.ToString().Split(',');
            foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
            {
                Val.Append(",(");
                for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
                {
                    if (r[columnName[j]] != null)
                    {
                        Val.Append("'" + r[columnName[j]] + "'");
                        Val.Append(",");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Val.Append("null,");
                    }
                }
                Val.Append(")");
                Val.Remove(Val.Length - 2, 1);

            }
            finalVal = Val.ToString().Substring(1);
            Query = "Insert into " + table.TableName + "(" + Col + ")" + "Values" + finalVal;
            EduDB.ExecuteNonQuery(Query);
        }
```

Comment: What text contains `TextBox1.Text` and what does `DataTable1.Rows[0][0]` contain after you've assigned it? Do you notice the issue only in the rendered HTML or also in the debugger?

Comment: Datatable "Datatable1" contains the text which is written in TextBox "TextBox1" and it ignores the starting spaces which we give while writing in textbox

Comment: DataTable doesn't modify the values you store in any way. Either you do the trimming when you store the values in the database, when processing the user's entry or when you retrieve the value from the database. Put some breakpoints and ensure that TextBox1.Text actually contains the spaces, that they are stored in the database and when you read them, that the resulting value actually does contain the spaces

Comment: Please see the edits in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be trimming the string befor inserting into database. Please check that out